# Jest testing with props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

React, typescript, and jest are all new to me.  I have a component, 'myContacts,' displaying tabs and tab panels with contacts; an address book.

Here is a portion of myContacts.

```
import ... as needed ... 

export default function myContacts( props ){

const { data, link } = props;

const [limit, setLimit] = useState<number>(data.limit);


(handleTabsChange and various other logic)

useEffect(() => {
    const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
    setContactsPerPage(
      entries[currentTab?.activeKey]?.slice(offset, offset + limit)
    );
    setLimit(viewData.limit);
  }, [entries, currentTab?.activeKey, page, limit, data.limit]);

  if (currentTab?.activeKey == null) {
    return null;
  }


return (
 <div>
    <Tabs
            index={tabIndex}
            onChange={handleTabsChange}
          >
            <TabList>
              {tabs.map((item: string) => (
                <Tab key={item}>{item}</Tab>
              ))}
            </TabList>
            <TabPanels>
              {tabs.map((item: string) => (
                <TabPanel key={item}>
                     ...  do some stuff ... 
                    />
                  ))}
                </TabPanel>
              ))}
            </TabPanels>
          </Tabs>
          <Container>
            <div className="w-full md:w-8/12">
              <Pagination
                totalEntries={entries[currentTab?.activeKey]?.length}
                limit={data.limit}
                page={page}
                setPage={setPage}
              />
            </div>
          </Container>
    </div>

 );
}
```

Here is the test I am working on. Very simple. Check that myContacts has rendered.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import myContacts from "../myContacts";

test("render contacts", () => {
  render(<myContacts />);
  expect(screen.getByText(/component myContacts/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

However, I am getting the following error.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'limit')

```
  23 |   const { link, route, viewData } = props;
  24 |
> 25 |   const [limit, setLimit] = useState<number>(viewData.limit);
```

My initial thought was to do the following:

```
test("render contacts", () => {
const limit = 5;

  render(<myContacts limit={limit} />);
  expect(screen.getByText(/component myContacts/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

but this resulted in the same error.

I know this error is because 'limit' is not defined in the test, but I am at a loss on how to define and pass it in the test.

Comment: Your props are `data` and `link`, so in your test you would write something like `<myContacts data={{limit: 5}} />`

Comment: Your component is also named against some naming conventions.  Change it to something like `MyContacts`